# Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: client version 1.22 is too old

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I get the following error  building my ASPNETCORE Web Api Project.
When I created the project I checked Docker For Windows.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "CleanWorkspace" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version.

For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting ---> Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: client version 1.22 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerComposeClient.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerComposeClient.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerComposeClient.<DownAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerWorkspace.<CleanWorkspaceAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.BuildTasks.DockerBaseTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets  208
```

Answer (score 6):

This was because I was switched to Windows containers. Switching to Unix resolved it.

Comment: Seems it is important not to confuse checking Docker for Windows with actually having docker switched to windows.